# Updating managed metadata when posting Repost Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I have a power Automate flow that creates a repost page in SharePoint Online.
I want to add some managed metadata to the post when it is created but produce an error.
Any direction I could be taking for t

this is my flow.

[image]

and this is what I have tried with the error.

[image]

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The property 'newsSource' does not exist on type 'SP.Publishing.RepostPage'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."}}}
```

clientRequestId: 11d63f6d-af04-450a-9f9b-d27b1bbd93a8
serviceRequestId: 97ca19a0-e085-0000-e2a7-43b4d1ac0a55

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.
I added a get items only returning one record, sorted by latest post.
Created a variable from the output to carry the ID over to my update item.

[image]